# Php companion alternative for Atom IDE

Tags: php, laravel-5, namespaces, ide, atom-editor

I switched from using sublime text to using Atom but One great package I am missing is php companion which allow importing of namespaces and classes in laravel.

I searched a lot but can't find any package like that for Atom and was wondering if anyone already found one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found package to generate "use" and namespace statement. https://github.com/aegypius/atom-php-fellow